# how to display dialog when moving from 1 tab to another - implementation uses Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have created a fragment activity with 3 tabs. When I move from tab 1 to tab 3, it takes around 5 seconds to load tab 3( due to some time consuming task ). During this loading time, I want to show a dialog.

I put the dialog inside onTabSelected(), but the dialog shows up only after the 3rd tab display comes up. I want it to show between "the time I clicked the 3rd tab" and "the time the 3rd tab actually comes up". Please do let me know ur suggestions.

Editted :

Sample code :

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.trial;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Window;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM ="selected_navigation_item";
ProgressDialog nDialog;

Fragment dashboardFrag = new DashboardTab();
Fragment Tab1 = new Tab1();
Fragment Tab2 = new Tab2();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1")
    .setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2")
    .setTabListener(this));

actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3")
    .setTabListener(this));

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
        savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
}
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar()
    .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {


if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, Tab1).commit();    
}
else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, Tab2).commit();    
}
else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
showProgress1();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, dashboardFrag).commit();
}

}

void showProgress1(){
nDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); //Here I get an error: The     constructor ProgressDialog(PFragment) is undefined
nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
nDialog.setTitle("Fetching Data");
nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
nDialog.setCancelable(true);
nDialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
}
```

**Tab1.java**

```
package com.example.trial;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

}
```

**Tab2.java**

```
package com.example.trial;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

}
```

**DashboardTab.java**

```
package com.example.trial;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DashboardTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rootView;
}

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

</FrameLayout>
```

**tab1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tab1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**tab2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="tab2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dashBoard"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have to show dialog or progress bar on your fragment in which your using time consuming as per my opinion.

Comment: @Duggu That is the content of the target tab. I want to show the dialog before that.

Comment: you must have to show dialog on target tab where your time consuming work start and hide when your work is completed .

Comment: @Duggu what happens is : Tab 1 displayed -> click on tab 3 -> for 5 secs display shows tab1 -> Then tab3. ( Time consuming part in tab 3 code ) What I want is : Tab1  displayed -> click on tab 3 -> start dialog -> for 5 secs display shows tab1 -> dismiss dailog in tab3.

Comment: not getting you and what you want to try right now means want to show dialog before not a right approach in my opinion

Comment: Suppose, your time consuming task is performed inside any mehod, so show dialog before that method call & dismiss dialog after the completion of the method. you cannot put dialog between the transection of one fragment to another fragment. If you are performing your task inside asyncTask then show dialog onPreExecute() & dismiss it onPostExecute() methods.

Comment: @Duggu : I have edited my post giving a sample code. If you have time please execute it to understand the problem better. Thanks.

Comment: @ZeeshanSaiyed : I have edited my post giving a sample code. If you have time please execute it to understand the problem better. Thanks.

Comment: @Duggu I gave a sample code since you said you could not understand the issue, to help others get a better understanding of what I am trying to say. I did not expect any spoon feeding here !!

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find something like you are telling, may be you are having issues with your phone memory, however an approach to show dialog when performing time consuming tasks through your code

```
public class DashboardTab extends Fragment {

    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard, container, false);

        showProgress1();
        YourTimeConsumingTask();
        nDialog.dismiss();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void YourTimeConsumingTask(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void showProgress1() {
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); // Here I get an error:
                                                            // The constructor
                                                            // ProgressDialog(PFragment)
                                                            // is undefined
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Fetching Data");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();

    }

}
```